# DbContext with dynamic DbSet

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

Is it possible to have a DbContext that has only one property of the generic type IDbSet and not a collection of concrete IDbSet e.g. DbSet.

More specifically, i want to create only one generic DbSet where the actual type will be determined dynamically e.g.

```
 public new IDbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class
 {
     return context.Set<T>();
 }
```

I don't want to create multiple DbSets e.g.

```
DbSet<product> Products { get; set; }
...
```

Actually i tried to use that generic DbSet but there seems to be one problem. The DbContext doesn't create the corresponding tables in the database. So although i can work with the in-memory entity graph, when the time comes to store the entites into the DB an exception is thrown (Invalid object name 'dbo.Product'.)

Is there any way to force the EF to create tables that correspond to dynamicaly creates DbSets?

Comment: You can do this, but the context should contain correct mapping information of all entities you want to fetch or update through it (directly or indirectly).

Comment: Do you mean the fluent api or attribute mappings?

Comment: Either. It's just two different ways to do the same thing.

Comment: well, i think i do apply those mappings.  
builder.Configurations.Add(new ProductMap());


is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes. But if Product has related entities, these should be in the mapping as well. Basically, what is in your _in-memory entity graph_? These objects must be in the mapping.

Comment: It still seems to me strange, because the product entity has 3 properties all of which are primitives; and that's the only entity i have right now.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes you can do this.**

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add
```

The DBSet entries will be derived.

If you plan to use POCOs and just build the model this way ok.
So you save Manual DBSet<> declaration...

But if you plan on being more Dynamic without POCOs...

Before you go down the this route, there are a number of things to consider.

- Have you selected the right ORM ?
- Do you plan on having a POCOs ?
- Why is DbSet Products { get; set; }   so bad ?
  You get a lot of action for that 1 line of code.
- What Data access approach you plan to use without types DBSets
- Do you plan to use Linq to Entity statements?
- do you plan on creating Expression trees for the Dynamic Data access  necessary. Since the types arent known at compile time.
- Do you plan to use the DB Model cache,?
- How will the cache be managed, especially in Web. ASP environments.

There are most likely other issues i did think of off the top of my head.
Constructing the model yourself is a big task. The Linq access is compromised when compile time types/POCOs are NOT used and the model cache and performance become critical management tasks.

The practical side of this task is not to under estimate
Start here  [bContext.OnModelCreating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

> Typically, this method is called only once when the first instance of
>   a derived context is created. The model for that context is then
>   cached and is for all further instances of the context in the app
>   domain. This caching can be disabled by setting the ModelCaching
>   property on the given ModelBuidler, but this can seriously degrade
>   performance. More control over caching is provided through use of the
>   DbModelBuilder and DbContext classes directly.

[The modelbuilder class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbmodelbuilder%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Good Luck

Comment: You can also use `modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(YourContext).Assembly)`